# Limitar uso de Memória RAM no R

Tags: r, matriz, memória

Estou rodando algumas análises e gostaria de fixar o uso de memória RAM no R para conseguir utilizar outros softwares simultaneamente sem que haja problema. Então gostaria, por exemplo,  limitar a 4Gb de memória RAM, mesmo fazendo com que a análise fique mais demorada.

Tentei esta estratégia [disponível aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-or-decreasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes), onde se cria um limite nas propriedades do programa, mas não funciona.

Atualmente estou trabalhando com cálculo de matrizes de distância 62 variáveis x 60 mil observações.

Outra opção era usar o h20, mas acabo usando mais RAM por ter que chamar o JAVA.

Comment: Eu não entendo nada de [tag:r], mas o problema todo me parece mais algum "erro" de como projetou o script, por exemplo, a FALTA de um *delay* entre uma série de operações e outra ocasionaria tal problema, se o algorítimo for escrito bem e com uma boa estratégia é provável que o consumo de memória raramente precise de absurdos 4GB (tudo isto me parece um exagero, mas posso estar enganado).

Comment: Tentou isto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1395256/1518921 ?

Comment: Experimente `memory.limit(size = 4000)`. Se está concatenando várias análises, também é uma boa ideia limpar o espaço de trabalho a cada etapa, p.e. salvando objetos em arquivos, apagando objetos que não serão mais usados e usando `gc()` para limpar a memória.

Comment: Obrigada @GuilhermeNascimento, talvez eu esteja programando meio errado o código. Pois estou fazendo uma análise relativamente pesada, vou tentar introduzir tempo entre elas. O R está ocupando minha RAM completamente.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoLagosta, obrigada pela indicação. Não conhecia o comando gc() e vou testar o limite de memória deste modo.  De fato estou acumulando mt objetos ao longo do código, vou tentar eliminá-los. Todo caso acho q analise de Space Join  é meio pesada.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoLagosta deu este erro: In memory.limit(size = 4000) : cannot decrease memory limit: ignored, estou procurando como resolver, mas nada resolutivo até o momento

Comment: Se está rodando uma análise pesada e/ou com muitos dados, então parta para otimização de código ao invés de tentar limitar o uso de RAM. Mas esse é um tópico muito amplo.

Comment: Qual o Sistema Operacional em que você está rodando a análise? Compartilhe o resultado de `sessionInfo()`, pode nos ajudar a entender o caso

Comment: Estou utilizando o Windows 7 64bits, a versão do R é a 3.6.1.

R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

A análise em tese é simples em termos de comandos é simples são três comandos: 2 são para abrir os arquivos e o último é para realizar space join entre shape de polígonos e pontos.